# Proper name for the Admin or Backend site

Tags: user-expectation

I am developing a web application which has three basic entry points:

1. Public or front access which is accessible by the general public.
2. Admin, back, or private access which is accessible by the administrators who maintain the site described above.
3. Super admin access which is only accessible by me.

What would the individuals who utilize the #2 access (i.e. administrators who maintain the sites) expect the public/front section and the admin/back/private section to be called?

Comment: Without wishing to be trite, can you not ask them? Or see what the same thing is called in other systems they use?

Comment: @Peter  I currently don't have any user's to ask :(  and am just in initial development. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if theres a proper name for it but I know a couple places/people that call it the "Dev Site" or "WebDev" or really anything that signifies that this is for the developers/administrators. This is in comparison to "Prod" or "Production" sites which is the front end publicly accessible site.

Comment: @DasBeasto  I think names like this are meant more for people in the industry.  I more wish to meet the expectations of joomla/wordpress users.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla refer to admin, or administration.

Backend as a term more associated with programming, and alongside/opposed to frontend

Comment: Thanks DjungleDev.  Do you know what Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla refer as the public facing side?

Comment: Had same answer in mind.

Comment: Doing a little research on what Wordpress refers it to.  Sometimes "dashboard", but I don't think I agree.  Search the phrase "joomla frontend verse backend" or the same for wordpress, and there is a lot of confusion.    Yes, I get that the backend is often referred to the code behind the code or even the server code.  See http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Front_End, and the frontend is the public side.  If one goes with frontend, then backend makes sense.  But so does admin.  Yikes!

Comment: Per Joomla, "The Administrator application, also known as the Back-end, Admin Panel or Control Panel, is the interface where administrators and other site officials with appropriate privileges can manipulate the look of a Joomla! powered web site. "  Would be nice to have one consistent name.  I haven't found much one what the public side should be called.

Comment: Indeed there is some discrepancy in terms. For CMS type web apps the front end is often simply the _site_.